# Problem with a code that does not do what it should?

Tags: python, url, bots, telethon

```
@events.register(events.NewMessage(chats='tubot'))
async def mi_handler(event):
 client = event.client
 if 'A big' in event.raw_text: 
  async for message in client.iter_messages('tubot', limit=1, from_user='tubot'): 
   await message.click(0) 
  url = event.message.buttons[0][0].url 
  print(url)
  await event.client.send_message('mybot', url.split('=')[1])
```

This code does something to me that had never happened to me before:
The code should do is: when the message appears in the ¨tubot¨, it should press the button and unlock the url, then a part of that url will send it to my bot called ¨mybot¨.
BUT:
when the message arrives in ´tubot´ the code click on the button and unlock the url, but it does not forward it to ´mybot´.
however when that message with the button already unlocked I manually forward it to "tubot" the code does forward it perfectly to ´mybot´

I have tried the following:
1- await asyncio.sleep(0.2) put an await between clicking on the button and reading the url and nothing didn't work.
2- even separate the code into two parts, one that clicks the button and another that forwards and nothing did not work
3- I made a group I put the code to click on the 'tubot' message and forward it to the group and another code that reads the message in that group with the button already unlocked and forwards the url to 'mybot' and nothing did not work. Even in the group, if I forward the message with the unlocked button, it reads me the url perfectly and it forwards me perfectly to 'mybot' but if it does the code doesn't work

Comment: Try to enable `logging` to find out what's happening or if the code is failing with some error. You also don't need to `iter_messages` to get the last message. It's the event. You should be able to just `event.click(...)` the button you need.

Comment: the problem is that the code does not fail with any error, it just does not forward the url